# Browsers not showing the protocol, key exchange and cipher information for my site using proper signed certificate for https

Tags: cipher-selection

Browsers not showing the protocol, key exchange and cipher information for my site using proper signed certificate for https, but the debug from a java client accessing the same site shows following information:

```
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1490496321 bytes = { 66, 137, 113, 105, 106, 27, 21, 88, 87, 171, 101, 163, 48, 196, 98, 95, 61, 89, 178, 47, 146, 65, 65, 124, 89, 82, 61, 93 }
Session ID:  {89, 215, 43, 65, 38, 153, 110, 30, 167, 95, 49, 89, 125, 4, 140, 66, 116, 122, 88, 188, 234, 174, 222, 2, 21, 92, 125, 239, 168, 12, 35, 165}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

Follows the security tab info in chrome:

```
This page is secure (valid HTTPS).
Valid Certificate
The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate.
View certificate
Secure TLS connection
**The connection to this site is using a strong protocol version and cipher suite.**
Secure Resources
All resources on this page are served securely.
```

Internet explorer : File -> Properties -> connection shows value as "Encrypted"
(without any details about the protocol, key exchange, cipher)

If I try to see the same for https://google.com, I can see all the fields ( protocol, key exchange, cipher) properly

E.g. On chrome

```
This page is secure (valid HTTPS).
Valid certificate
The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate.
View certificate
Secure connection
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using a strong protocol (QUIC), a strong key exchange (X25519), and a strong cipher (AES_128_GCM).
Secure resources
All resources on this page are served securely.
```

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what browsers are supposed to be showing but are not showing. And it's hard to tell given the lack of precision in your question, but if your problem is with the browser interface rather than with your site's configuration, this is a browser support question, not a security question.